# In Node.js, a loop calling a function defined in another JS file is making mistakes

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop

I have a server (made with Express in Node.js) that gets notifications of RSS feeds, gets data from their entries (title, date, link) and then "does something" with the data by calling a function defined in another JS file ("article_filter_toDB.js"). The code on the server-side is:

```
// parts omitted
var article_filter_toDB = require('./article_filter_toDB.js');

// parts omitted

client.on('notification', function (notification) {
    // gets notifications of RSS feeds

    entries = notification.entries;
    for (index = 0; index < entries.length; ++index) {
        title = entries[index].title;
        date = entries[index].published;
        link = entries[index].link.href;
        // gets data from the entry of the feed
        miniwords = 1000;
        // a variable that I set

        article_filter_toDB(link, title, miniwords);
        // "does something" by calling a function defined in another JS file ("article_filter_toDB.js")
    }
});

// parts omitted
```

What the function "article_filter_toDB" does is to get the content of the article given by the link from the RSS feed (using Request), parsing HTML code to count the words of the article, and, if this length is above "miniwords" (here 1000), save the data relative to the article (title, link, date...) to a database (MongoDB, via Mongoose).

Sometimes it works well. But sometimes it computes a length equal to 1 (that is, it was unable to really count the words) although, if I run the function "article_filter_toDB" separately (that is, the separate JS file, applied to same "link", "title", "miniwords" that I copy to it), it is able to correctly count the words.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

To be more complete, here is the code of the "article_filter_toDB.js" file:

```
// parts omitted
article_filter_toDB = function (link, title, miniwords) {

    Article.findOne({
        title: title
    }, 'title', function (err, articles) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        if (articles == null) {
            // ...if an article with this title is not already present in my database...

            // parts omitted here, that set the variable "balise" depending on the link

            request(link, function (err, resp, body) {
                $ = cheerio.load(body);
                texte = $(balise).text();
                content = texte.split(" ");
                length = content.length;
                // ...let's count its words with Request and Cheerio...

                if ((length > miniwords)) {
                    var newArticle = new Article({
                        site: url.parse(link).hostname.replace(/^www\./, ''),
                        date: date,
                        link: link,
                        title: title,
                        length: length,
                    });
                    newArticle.save(function (err, newArticle) {
                        if (err) return console.error(err)
                    });
                    // if the article's length is more than the number given by "miniwords", let's save its data in my database

                }
            });
        }
    });
}

module.exports = article_filter_toDB;
// exportation of the function to use it elsewhere
```

Comment: Can you show the other file that contains the function?

Comment: I just added it to the question above.

Comment: To be clear: sometimes the whole thing works, since I really get articles saved into my database. But I've also noticed, thanks to intermediate verification that I introduced, that sometimes, an article is counted with 1 word (it's counted, that is the function seems to be called) although it has more words in reality... and although the "article_filter_toDB" function, when run separately, is doing the job correctly when I launch it separately...

Answer (score 1):

This how you call functions from another file properly in node.js

```
// otherfile.js
// ========
module.exports = {
  article_filter_toDB: function (link, title, miniwords) {
    // do stuff here
  },
};
```

Then on your code:

```
var otherfile = require('./otherfile');
...
otherfile.article_filter_toDB(link, title, miniwords);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already done that. The problem is not that the function is not called at all, it is that sometimes its final steps are not correctly done...

Comment: @GBC you might also want to show the other function.

Comment: I just added it to the question above.

Comment: To be clear: sometimes the whole thing works, since I really get articles saved into my database. But I've also noticed, thanks to intermediate verification that I introduced, that sometimes, an article is counted with 1 word (it's counted, that is the function seems to be called) although it has more words in reality... and although the "article_filter_toDB" function, when run separately, is doing the job correctly when I launch it separately...